# Find minimum length of substring to rearrange for palindromic string

Tags: c++, palindrome

There is a string s. What is minimum length of substring to rearrange for making string s palindrome.

Example:

**Input:** abbaabbca

**Output:** 4

I can rearrange substring from index **4 to 7 (abbc)**, and get **abbacabba**

It is guaranteed that there is palindrome after rearrange.

---

Is there a way to solve it using modification of Manacher's or some other text algorithm?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit to show your work. Currently you've only provided a high level requirement, without showing any work or specific issue.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't provided any work. But, everything I did was brute force solution which is not good.
I wanted to know can some algorithms help me.
Thanks for detailed explanation, I'm very thankful.

Comment: Well, next time around when you encounter a problem like this, I suggest to just try to solve it by hand, play around with it and see what are the possibilities. You have to develop a 'feel' for what kind of algorithm those problems demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not the case for standard text processing algorithms. It is so simple you don't need them - there is only one reshuffled part of the string, so four situations can occur.

1. `'ppssXXXXXXXpp'`
2. `'ppXXXXXsssspp'`
3. `'ppsssiiiXXXpp'`
4. `'ppXXXiiissspp'`

where

- *pp* is the outer part that is already palindromic ( may be zero )
- *XX* is the part we reshuffle
- *ss* is the part we leave as it is ( and reshuffle the XX to match it )
- *ii* is the inner part around the center that is also already palindromic ( may be zero )

we can check and clip the outer palindromic part first, leaving us with `'ssXXXXXXX'` , `'XXXXXssss'` , `'sssiiiXXX'` or `'XXXiiisss'`

Then we use the symmetry - if the middle part exists, we can arbitrarily choose which side we keep and which we shuffle to adapt to the other, so we just do one.
When there is no middle palindromic part, we simply run the same check but starting from opposite directions and then we choose the one that gave the shorter substring

So, let's proceed from the start. We will simply take one character after the other
`'s--------'`
`'ss-------'`
`'sss------'`

and stop when the rest of the string would not be any longer made to match the rest.

When does that happen ? When the 'ssss... part of the string already gobbled up more than a half of all occurrences of a character, then it will be missing on the other side and it can't be made to match by shuffling.

On the other hand, we will always eat up more than a half of each character's occurrences after passing the middle of the string. So three situations can occur.

1. we run short of the middle. In that case we have found the string to reshuffle. `'sssXXXXXXXXXXXX'`
2. we reach the middle. Then we can search for the inner part that is palindromic too, yielding something like `'ssssiiiiXXXX'`
3. there is a special case you reach the middle of an odd-sided string - there has to be the one odd count character there. If it is not there, you will have to proceed as with 1)

The resulting algorithm  ( in java, [already tried it here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/l2NQP2cziG) ) :

```java
package palindrometest;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class PalindromeTest {

    static int[] findReshuffleRange( String s ) {
        // first the easy part,
        //split away the already palindromatic start and end if there is any
        int lo = 0, hi = s.length()-1;
        while(true) {
            if( lo >= hi ) {
                return new int[]{0,0}; // entire string a palindrome
            }
            if( s.charAt(lo) != s.charAt(hi) ) {
                break;
            }
            lo++;
            hi--;
        }

        // now we compute the char counts and things based on them
        Map<Character,Integer> charCounts = countChars( s, lo, hi );
        
        if( !palindromePossible( charCounts ) ) {
            return null;
        }
        
        Map<Character,Integer> halfCounts = halfValues( charCounts );
        
        char middleChar = 0;
        if( (s.length() % 2) != 0 ) { // only an odd-sized string has a middle char
            middleChar = findMiddleChar( charCounts );
        }

        // try from the beginning first
        int fromStart[] = new int[2];
        if(  findMiddlePart( fromStart, s, lo, hi, halfCounts, middleChar, false ) ) {

            // if the middle palindromatic part exist, the situation is symmetric
            // we don't have to check the opposite direction
            return fromStart;
        }

        // try from the end
        int fromEnd[] = new int[2];
        findMiddlePart( fromEnd, s, lo, hi, halfCounts, middleChar, true );

        // take the shorter
        if( fromEnd[1]-fromEnd[0] < fromStart[1]-fromStart[0] ) {
            return fromEnd;
        } else {
            return fromStart;
        }
    }

    static boolean findMiddlePart( int[] result, String s, int lo, int hi, Map<Character,Integer> halfCounts, char middleChar, boolean backwards ) {
        Map<Character,Integer> limits = new HashMap<>(halfCounts);
        int pos, direction, end, oth;
        if( backwards ) {
            pos = hi;
            direction = -1;
            end = (lo+hi)/2; // mid rounded down
            oth = (lo+hi+1)/2; // mid rounded up
        } else {
            pos = lo;
            direction = 1;
            end = (lo+hi+1)/2; // mid rounded up
            oth = (lo+hi)/2; // mid rounded down
        }
        
        // scan until we run out of the limits
        while(true) {
            char c = s.charAt(pos);
            int limit = limits.get(c);
            if( limit <= 0 ) {
                break;
            }
            limits.put(c,limit-1);
            pos += direction;
        }
        
        // whether we reached the middle
        boolean middleExists = pos == end && ( oth != end || s.charAt(end) == middleChar );
        
        if( middleExists ) {
            // scan through the middle until we find the first non-palindromic character
            while( s.charAt(pos) == s.charAt(oth) ) {
                pos += direction;
                oth -= direction;
            }
        }
        
        // prepare the resulting interval
        if( backwards ) {
            result[0] = lo;
            result[1] = pos+1;
        } else {
            result[0] = pos;
            result[1] = hi+1;
        }
        return middleExists;
    }

    static Map<Character,Integer> countChars( String s, int lo, int hi ) {
        Map<Character,Integer> charCounts = new HashMap<>();
        for( int i = lo ; i <= hi ; i++ ) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            int cnt = charCounts.getOrDefault(c,0);
            charCounts.put(c,cnt+1);
        }
        return charCounts;
    }

    static boolean palindromePossible(Map<Character,Integer> charCounts) {
        int oddCnt = 0;
         for( int cnt : charCounts.values() ) {
            if( (cnt % 2) != 0 ) {
                oddCnt++;
                if( oddCnt > 1 ) {
                    return false; // can not be made palindromic
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    static char findMiddleChar( Map<Character,Integer> charCounts ) {
        Map<Character,Integer> halfCounts = new HashMap<>();
        for( Map.Entry<Character,Integer> e : charCounts.entrySet() ) {
            char c = e.getKey();
            int cnt = e.getValue();
            if( (cnt % 2) != 0 ) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
        
    static Map<Character,Integer> halfValues( Map<Character,Integer> charCounts ) {
        Map<Character,Integer> halfCounts = new HashMap<>();
        for( Map.Entry<Character,Integer> e : charCounts.entrySet() ) {
            char c = e.getKey();
            int cnt = e.getValue();
            halfCounts.put(c,cnt/2); // we round *down*
        }
        return halfCounts;
    }
    
    static String repeat(char c, int cnt ) {
        return cnt <= 0 ? "" : String.format("%"+cnt+"s","").replace(" ",""+c);
    }
    
    static void testReshuffle(String s ) {
        int rng[] = findReshuffleRange( s );
        if( rng == null ) {
            System.out.println("Result : '"+s+"' is not palindromizable");
        } else if( rng[0] == rng[1] ) {
            System.out.println("Result : whole '"+s+"' is a palindrome");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Result : '"+s+"'");
            System.out.println("          "+repeat('-',rng[0])+repeat('X',rng[1]-rng[0])+repeat('-',s.length()-rng[1]) );
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        testReshuffle( "abcdefedcba" );
        testReshuffle( "abcdcdeeba" );
        testReshuffle( "abcfdeedcba" );
        testReshuffle( "abcdeedbca" );
        testReshuffle( "abcdefcdeba" );
        testReshuffle( "abcdefgfcdeba" );
        testReshuffle( "accdefcdeba" );
    }
}
```

Comment: You've posted a very detailed answer to a question that has no effort shown: no code, no specific problem Please don't do this.

Comment: I don't think being harsh to newcomers is the right way.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be harsh. The issue is, many people post various challenges from classroom/homework assignments, without showing work, and then look to the Community to solve their particular issue. In this case, the OP simply didn't show their work, so... effectively, you did their work for them. It's best to comment and request that the OP edit their question to show their work, specific issues, etc. This discourages such behavior.

Comment: Assuming he/she was just lazy, as opposed to not even knowing where to start to begin with, *is* being harsh.

Answer (score -1):

you can use like this

```
bool morethanone(string s, char c)
{
    // Count variable
    int res = 0;
 
    for (int i=0;i < s.length(); i++)
 
        // checking character in string
        if (s[i] == c)
            res++;
 
    if(res > 1) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;     
}

int getsubstringlength(string text)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        if(morethanone(text, text[i]))
            result++;
    }
    return result / 2;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. For example on string 'aaaaabaaa' it says 8 where it should return 2.

Comment: You've posted a very detailed answer to a question that has no effort shown: no code, no specific problem Please don't do this.